# LLVM compiler - Is this an optimization bug?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, llvm, compiler-optimization

I have an interesting problem related to the optimization level of LLVM compiler. I'm using:

- Xcode 8.2.1
- LLVM 8.0

It is better to explain it with an example code. I boiled down the problem into a simple objective-c class. Please see the code below first:

```c
@interface Foo()  {
    BOOL is_loading;
}
@end

@implementation Foo

- (void)test {

    printf("started loading \n");

    // set loading flag to YES
    is_loading = YES;

    // schedule a timer to fire in 2 seconds, to simulate the end of loading
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.0
                                     target:self
                                   selector:@selector(timerFired)
                                   userInfo:nil
                                    repeats:NO];

    // wait asynchronously until loading flag is set to NO
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

        while (is_loading) {
            // loop until timer event modifies is_loading flag 
        }

        printf("finished loading \n");
    });
}

- (void)timerFired {

    printf("timer fired \n");

    // set loading flag to NO
    is_loading = NO;

}

@end
```

If you instantiate class `Foo` and call `load` method, it will simulate a loading progress and asynchronously observe `is_loading` flag to determine if the loading is finished.

And after that, the console output will be like this:

```
started loading
timer fired
finished loading
```

But if you turn on the compiler optimization, you will see this output instead:

```
started loading
timer fired
```

Apparently the while loop never ends and execution cannot reach the next printf() message.

Am I missing an obvious reason for this to happen, or can it be an optimizer bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Apple states on their [synchronization page](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/ThreadSafety/ThreadSafety.html) the compiler may well not load the variable more than once when the code is optimized. It doesn't know that it may be edited from another thread so this happens.

Marking the variable as `volatile` will force the compiler to load the value each time it's needed and this won't happen.

Comment: Thank you, that worked.. It's time to blade my knowledge about `volatile` :)

Comment: I want to add, that simply adding `volatile` does *not* make the code thread safe, so it still can fail.

Comment: It's unfortunate that this answer was accepted. Busy-looping on a volatile may work in this case but it will have some downright nasty side effects, such as maxing out your CPU utilization.

Comment: @DietrichEpp Yes, should've said that it is not the proper way to do things but the question was about why the code is optimized this way. Could add but there's already another answer with that information.

Answer (score 1):

Even Sami's answer is an answer to your Q, it maybe is misleading.

Since `volatile` variables are *not* thread safe, your whole approach can fail, when blocks form two different threads access `is_loading`. The usage of `volatile` is *not* intended for thread synchronization.

Use GCD semaphores instead.